# Python exercise problem - Name error when running function

Tags: python

I am doing a python course and one of the exercises is to write a function that adds "Doctor" to a name. The instructions are:

Define function make_doctor()  that takes a parameter name
get user input for variable full_name
call the function using full_name   as argument
print the return value

My code is:

```
def make_doctor(name):
    full_name = input("Doctor ")
    return full_name

print(make_doctor(full_name))
```

However, I keep getting the below error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-da98f29e6ceb> in <module>()
      5     return full_name
      6 
----> 7 print(make_doctor(full_name))

NameError: name 'full_name' is not defined
```

Can you anybody help please?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't assigned a value to the name `full_name` yet, so Python doesn't know what value to pass to the function call. Your function doesn't make use of the `name` parameter anyway; the call to `input` should be made *before* you call `make_doctor`, not *in* the call.

Comment: You want something like `full_name = input(); print(make_doctor(full_name))`, although it's not clear what `make_doctor` is actually supposed to *do* with the name.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the variable `full_name` is a local variable to the function `make_doctor`

Try this :

```
def make_doctor(name):
    return "Doctor "+name

full_name = input()
print(make_doctor(full_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You code has lots of issues.

Have the `input` be outside the function. Pass the input to `make_doctor` to add "Doctor" to it, and then print that.

Very important side note: Use `raw_input()` if python2 and `input()` if python3. dont use `input()` in python 2 its an expression evaluator rather than a string.

```
def make_doctor(name):
    return "Doctor {}".format(name)

name = raw_input("Enter your name here!!") # if python2
# name = input("Enter your name here!!") # if python3
print(make_doctor(name=name))
```